# MongoDB - How to replace specified field with $cond only when the condition is `True`?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

here's my document:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    status: "estimate.sent",
    request_info: {request_id: 1, request_status: "done"},
    estimate_info: {
        estimate_id: 1
        estimate_status: "sent",
        expire_date: "2022-12-08T05:49:56.908149"
    }
}
```

and what I'm trying to do is to change `estimate_info.estimate_status`'s value to `expired` if `expire_date` is less than today's datetime.

so I'm currently running query following like this (I'm using pymongo FYI):

```
today = datetime.utcnow()
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {_id: 1}},
        {$addFields: {
            "estimate_info.estimate_status": {$cond: [
                {$and: [
                    {$eq: [$status, "estimate.sent"]},
                    {$lt: [$estimate_info.expire_date, today]}
                    ]
                }, "expired", "$estimate_info.estimate_status"]
            }}
        }
    ]
)
```

it works fine, but what i expected is doing nothing if the `$cond` expression is `false`. because if `status` is not equal to `estimate.sent`, `estimate_info` must be null, not `{}`. My query returns `{}` when the expression is false. is there any fancy way to replace fields depending on condition as I expected?

Comment: For Python, your shown `dict`s aren't valid - they seem to be missing lots of quotes.  What is `$estimate_info.expire_info`?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vCk74h_FOiD

Comment: @Noel It still returns `{}` not `null`